# C# Read ost,pst file when Outlook, Skype for business is running

Tags: c#, wpf, filestream

I've built a WPF application which is **reading** an OST/PST file. Everything works fine if the programs that use that file are closed (not running).

So in order to read an **OST** file, I need to first close the (Outlook, Skype) which is not practical at all (it means I become offline during working hours)

I've tried to read it with those options:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)){ }
```

Which throws an exception: "The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file."

Questions:

- Is it possible to read a file which is used by another process like Outlook (i suppose, that it has some special permissions "Microsoft"?

  -When I open/read OST file fist with my program and then when I try to open Outlook it takes away my read permissions (handle) and gives the Outlook a handle to access the file?

  -Since is it a file which is used by Microsoft products it has some kind of privileges for who can use it at a given time?

Please give me ideas, solutions on how can I only **READ** OST/PST files when Outlook... is running. (my program reads Calendar events and displays them).

Comment: If an application has the file open and disallowed sharing, then no, you cannot open that file at the same time. There is, however, a way of obtaining a shadow copy of the file, this is the API used for backing up files from your computer. You should google "Volume Shadow Copy API" and see if there is something you can use from there.

Comment: There are no "special permissions". Multiple applications can open the same file if they open it with a file sharing flag. If an application doesn't allow sharing, you can't open it and *shouldn't* try because you may end up reading inconsistent data. If a file isn't written with sharing in mind, you have no way of knowing whether the data is consistent or not, whether the application is in the middle of writing or flushing etc

Comment: *Why* do you want to open the files themselves instead of eg using Outlook interop?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Good idea, I will take a look and try this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've used this GitHub repository [link] (https://github.com/Dijji/XstReader) , and i found it very simple to use and to adjust code for my needs, in all other ways of reading calendars in Outlook i always had an issue when reading a **Shared calendar** (VBA, Interop), couldn't read it at all. What would be the benefits of using Outlook interop for reading outlook calendar with it?

Comment: @SašoPavlič you'll be able to read the calendar even when Outlook is using it